# InvalidArgumentException: Auth guard [admin] is not defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-echo, laravel-websockets

I'm using Laravel echo locally hence using the

```
forceTLS: false
```

in bootstrap.js

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'local',
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    encrypted: true,
    disableStats: true,
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6001,
    forceTLS: false,
});
```

but when I add the

```
forceTLS: false
```

code in the above code block I'm getting an error

```
InvalidArgumentException: Auth guard [admin] is not defined.
```

and when I comment it out, that error is not there anymore. I have tried

```
php artisan config:clear and php artisan config:cache
```

but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Check guards in your config/auth.php file
Make sure you have admin guard!